# How can I join two splines in the mask editor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

I wanted to create a rounded equilateral triangle mask.
I started by adding a circle, deleting one of the handles, and adjusting the angles of the other two…

[image: first]

…and then copying and rotating this arrangement twice:

[image: second]

Now I'd like to join the vertices of the splines to close a triangle.
I tried

- <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> for join, but these didn't work;
- <kbd>F</kbd> for face/edge, like in object edit mode, but this didn't work either;
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> with all selected for "Make Cyclic," but this didn't work (it made each individual spline cyclic).

I ended up just creating a wonky hexagon and zooming in to align the verts to "good enough" level:

[image: wonky semi-solution]

What's a better way to do this? How can I actually join the points?

Comment: Select only two points to be joined, then press F. Repeat for others points.